# How to make a 3 column chart with dividers using openoffice

Tags: openoffice

[image]

I'm interested in making a chart someone like the photo above using open office. Any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a simple 3-column table to me. To insert a new table in Writer, position the cursor where you want the table to appear and then use any of the following methods to open the *Insert Table* dialog box:

- From the main menu, select `Table > Insert > Table`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.
- From the Standard toolbar, click the Table icon: [image: 1]

Here you can specify the properties for the new table:

[image: 2]

Comment: Thank you, I'll probably need to ask a follow up question on formatting the table.