# Remove vertical lines from openoffice table

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice

As a follow up question to [How to make a 3 column chart with dividers using openoffice](https://superuser.com/questions/906185/how-to-make-a-3-column-chart-with-dividers-using-openoffice/906189#906189) , I created a table which looks like:

[image]

Is it possible to make horizontal lines invisible, to give the effect of just 3 columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the cells/rows whose borders you want to modify.
2. From the main menu, select `Table > Table Properties` to open the **Table Format** dialog box:

   [image: 1]
3. On the *Borders* tab you can click in the *User-defined* area and remove the borders you don't want.

Comment: Thank you, I realized after a while that the grid lines are always there in writer but don't necessarily show up  (unless you want them to ) in the outputted document.